# Image not Showing

Tags: android

Image is showing in studio but not in Phone.
Image is placed in res.
Running on one plus one.
using linear layout

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wifi"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
```

Comment: Please show you activity code.

Comment: is it a vector drawable?

Comment: please check the size of your image. If it is very big then add a small size image

Comment: try to set background instesd src

Answer (score 1):

You have to **add below line** in to your **root layout**.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Please see below example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <ImageView
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user_red"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

without **`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`** you can not use **`app:srcCompat`**.

Comment: you can ... then you'll have to give the packagename.classname containing this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Inside res folder there like **drawable**,**drawable-ldpi**,**drawable-mdpi**,**drawable-hdpi**,**drawable-xhdpi** etc.

You should make sure that you copied your image in **drawable** folder not in Idpi or mdpi

Answer (score -1):

try it by Changing the code to

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/wifi"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```